# Using margins in the header buttons

Tags: html, css

I have MainHeader container which has a width of 688px. My buttons are 212px each (total 336px) wide. Now since I wanted these button to have exactly same margins in left and right so that right, I have left-margin 8.6px and right-margin also 8.6px. But one of my button comes in the next line. What am I doing wrong in the calculation.

My CSS Style

```
.MainHeader{
    height:100px;
    width:688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:black;
    }
.BodyContainer{
    height:788px;
    width:688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:white;
    }
.MainFooter{
    height: 100px;
    width: 688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:black;
    }
.Button{
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    padding :0px 5px;
    background:darkorange;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 14px/30px arial;
    background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
a.Button{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

a.Button:hover{
    background: grey;
    }
ul{
    padding: 0;
    }
li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 8px;
margin-left: 8.6px;
}
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="MainHeader">
    <div>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Search</a></li>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? They look fine to me in 1 line here http://jsfiddle.net/baDQ6/

Comment: I am trying to get equal spacing between all those buttons. So since the header is 688 px wide and buttons are each 212 px wide (total 636px). Per my calculation now if I want to add left-marign and right-margin, it should be 8.6px each. When I apply that one of the buttons comes below two buttons in my browser.

Comment: px can't be in decimals

Comment: I just took the decimals out but its still the same. Also, if you could let me know what am I doing wrong in my calculation that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have border 1px on your bottom, that adds both left and right 1px. So you got to remove both sides 2px.remember to clear:both after all